# Writing to OR Reading from a file

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to write a program where the user has a choice to write data to a file OR read the file.

I don't know why my if-else if structure is not working correctly. When I try to view the data, the program displays the data and then asks for more input when it should not.

I will post what I have hoping someone can help with what seems like a foolish and simple problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Candy
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException
    {
        String candyname;
        String input="";

        //create scanner object
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("[V]iew or [A]ppend Database (V or A)?===>");
        String choice=keyboard.nextLine();

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("V"))
        {
            //open the file
            File file=new File("candy");
            Scanner inputFile=new Scanner(file);

            //display the lines
            while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                //read a line
                candyname=inputFile.nextLine();

                //display a line
                System.out.println(candyname);
            }

            //close the file
            inputFile.close();

            System.out.println("\nComplete!");
        }

        else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A"));
        {
            //open the file
            FileWriter fwriter=new FileWriter("candy", true);

            System.out.println("Type 'end' to STOP entering names\n");
            do
            {
                //get the name of the candy
                System.out.print("Enter the name of the candy===>");
                candyname=keyboard.nextLine();

                if (candyname.equalsIgnoreCase("end"))
                {
                    //break; //breaks out of loop
                    //or use a null if clause (empty)
                }
                else if (!(candyname.equalsIgnoreCase("end")))
                {
                    //append to file
                    PrintWriter outputFile=new PrintWriter(fwriter);
                    outputFile.println(candyname);
                }                

            }while (!(candyname.equalsIgnoreCase("end")));// || candyname !="END");

            //close the file
            fwriter.close();

            System.out.println("\nComplete!");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: What do you mean by `if-else if structure is not working correctly`? Please explain..

Comment: Tip: Use `"V".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)` instead of `choice.equalsIgnoreCase("V")` to eliminate the possibility of a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is here. OP posted an SSCCE illustrating the problem perfectly. Granted, the terminology wasn't exact but all you had to do was run the code provided to see the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Because your else if is closed

```
 else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A"));
```

remove semicolon **;**

```
 else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
```

Comment: Spotted this the second you posted it! Good timing :) +1

Comment: Good eye. Was looking for something like this but couldn't see it. +1

Comment: chris thanks for saving me hours to infinity...!